# LINQ GroupBy object with possible null values

Tags: c#, linq, null, group-by

I have a following GroupBy query:

```
var groups = ordered.GroupBy(k => new
        {
            a = k[SelectedFirstCategory], 
            b = k[SelectedSecondCategory], 
            c = k[SelectedThirdCategory]
        });
```

The problem is that Categories can be null.

How can I modify my GroupBy to accomodate for this. I know I could go with multiple "if" but that is not elegant for me.

To make this clearer an example would be that if SelectedSecondCategory is null but other are filled than resulting grouping should be according to "a" and "c" property.
I thought about null coalescent like this:

```
a = SelectedFirstCategory != null ? k[SelectedFirstCategory] : DON'T KNOW WHAT TU PUT HERE.
```

Alternative value should be something that would be irrelevant to groupBy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. If for one item a=1, b=2, c=1 and for the second a=1, b=null, c=1 than they should be in the same group or not?

Comment: what is the type of `SelectedFirstCategory`?

Answer (score 2):

I appears to be quite easy:

```
var groups = ordered.GroupBy(k => new  {
            a = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFirstCategory) ? k[SelectedFirstCategory] : null,
            b = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedSecondCategory) ? k[SelectedSecondCategory] : null,
            c = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedThirdCategory) ? k[SelectedThirdCategory] : null
        });
```

It appears that if some parameter of grouping is null it is not taken into consideration when creating a group so that is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper method,  Just be aware that you grouping may not make any sense.  Suppose you had you columns being "Fruit", "Color", "Shape".  Grouping ["Apple", "Red", "Round"] with ["Banana", "Oval"] doesn't give good results.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<object>> ordered = new List<List<object>>();
            int SelectedFirstCategory = 1;
            int SelectedSecondCategory = 2;
            int SelectedThirdCategory = 3;

            var groups = ordered.GroupBy(k => MyGroup(
                k[SelectedFirstCategory],
                k[SelectedSecondCategory],
                k[SelectedThirdCategory])
            );
        }
        static List<object> MyGroup(object a, object b, object c)
        {
            List<object> results = new List<object>();
            if (a != null) results.Add(a);
            if (b != null) results.Add(b);
            if (c != null) results.Add(c);

            return results;

        }​
```

Comment: That is what I said.  [a, null, c] is different from [a, c]

Comment: You said [a,b,c] is different than [a,c]. however sorting [a,c] or [a,c,null] gives me the same results.